# How to get a fade in text effect when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, fadein

I can get the animation itself working without scrolling. However, when I try to use JavaScript to insert the class during scrolling, it wont work. My code looks like:

JS:

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if(entry.isIntersecting){
    document.querySelectorALL(".animated")[0].classList.add(".fadeInLeft");
    }
  })
})
observer.observe(document.querySelector(".about"));
```

in my HTML, I have a container element with the class of .about that has the elements I'm trying to fade in with the class of .animated by adding in the animation effect with the class .fadeInLeft. thank you.

Comment: There is no such method as `querySelectorALL`. There is a method called [`querySelectorAll`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), though. [`add`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add) expects a list of class names. `.fadeInLeft` isn’t a class name; `fadeInLeft` is.

Comment: As @SebastianSimon pointed out...  `document.querySelectorALL(".animated")[0].classList.add(".fadeInLeft");` => should be => `document.querySelectorAll(".animated")[0].classList.add("fadeInLeft");` and really if you only want the first iteration of the nodelist then just query it using `document.querySelector(".animated").classList.add("fadeInLeft");`